# Prevent moving of a unique_ptr C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics, unique-ptr

Is there any way to prevent a user to explicity take ownership of a unique pointer with

```
 std::move
```

?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? You could wrap it in non-movable class.

Comment: Maybe you can pass it by const reference.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  How does the user have access to the `unique_ptr`?

Comment: I'm returnin a unique pointer, I want the user be able to call methods of that pointer without taking its ownership.

Comment: @DarioOO If you don't want the user to have any ownership, return a raw pointer.

Comment: @DarioOO: Er, when you returned in in a `unique_ptr` you gave it unique ownership, by definition. Who owns it otherwise?

Comment: As i thought people is misusing unique_ptr. I see things like returning opaque pointers to PIMPL believing that user can't take his ownership, this kind of questions should help users to prevent doing such things. so no understand for voting down ^^

Comment: "*I see things like returning opaque pointers to PIMPL believing that user can't take his ownership*" Where do you see these things?

Comment: he needs [this](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2013/n3514.pdf), actually

Comment: @DarioOO if you don't want to give up ownership, return by reference if it's guaranteed to be non-null; if it might be null, return by raw pointer (the link I gave above is a proposal for a "smart" pointer that explicitly doesn't own its pointee, for documentation purposes, but it's not in the standard)..once you return a `unique_ptr`, you've already given up ownership, regardless of whether or not the pointer is moved from again or not, so preventing a `std::move` won't help you

Comment: @DarioOO, you could also build something like `exempt_ptr` yourself, if you need the value to be possibly null but don't want to return a raw pointer...all it is is a wrapper that implements `operator*` and `operator->` but disallows most other actions and doesn't delete the pointee

Comment: this is that terrible of a question, by the way--there's no standard way right now to return a pointer but indicate that you want to retain ownership of it yourself (which is what the proposed `exempt_ptr` would do)...returning a raw pointer is ok but it leads to ambiguity about your intent (just like using a c-style cast instead of a c++ cast)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make it `const`

The `unique_ptr` move constructor takes a *non-const* rvalue reference, so can't be called with a `const` object.

```
const unique_ptr<int> owner(new int);
// ...
unique_ptr<int> thief = std::move(owner);  // ERROR
```

This allows `unique_ptr` to be used like a `boost::scoped_ptr`

Comment: this is good to know, but I suspect what the OP wants is not to give ownership to the caller at all, not just to prevent it from being moved from again (_"I'm returnin a unique pointer, I want the user be able to call methods of that pointer without taking its ownership. "_)--he probably needs to just return by reference instead

Comment: Ah I didn't see that comment - yes, just returning a reference makes a lot more sense

Comment: Couldn't a thief just cast away const? ;)

Comment: @FredOverflow could always just call `.get()` too, no?

Comment: @StephenLin Sure, but `.get()` returns a raw pointer. Unless you put that back into another `unique_ptr`, I don't see the problem.

Comment: @FredOverflow right, that's what i meant :) just saying it's easy enough to violate any smart pointer's contract without even doing anything that violates the type system, that's all

Comment: @FredOverflow, yes, security is never black & white, this will only stop casual, opportunistic thieves, not motivated thugs with weapons like `const_cast` :o) Or as I like to put it, you can make it difficult to accidentally misuse an interface but your code will never be safe against sufficiently motivated idiots who insist on breaking it!

Comment: @FredOverflow: No because the thief has no idea if the object is actually const or not, and if it is, it will be undefined behavior.

Answer (score 5):

By returning a `std::unique_ptr`, you have given up the control of the object. The new owner will either destroy it, or pass it to somebody else.

If you don't intend the user to release the object, then return a reference.

*you have `boost::scoped_ptr`/`const std::unique_ptr` (see Jonathan's answer) which technically answers your question -- the caller releases, but cannot give away the resource -- but I fail to see a compelling example of* why *would you need this rather that `std::unique_ptr` or a reference*

Comment: The problem for me was allowing extend a class without a chance to give outside the class the resource. Reference was not  good because the resource was injected through DI and the class responsible for resource lifetime. At same time a aliasing constructor binding the class and the resource made no sense because using the resource outside the class is not possibile. The context is object buffers in OpenGL.