# Non-Movable C++17 Unique Pointer

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17, unique-ptr

I came across this answer [Prevent moving of a unique_ptr C++11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15296881/prevent-moving-of-a-unique-ptr-c11). However while trying it out on a compiler online, this works with C++11(`std::move` compiler error) but with C++17, I'm seeing that the `std::move` below is successful. Shouldn't the compiler throw an error on that line? Also if some semantics have changed in C++17, what is the correct way to create a non movable unique_ptr in C++17 and onward.

```
template <typename T>
using scoped_ptr = const std::unique_ptr<T>;

int main()
{
    auto p = scoped_ptr<int>(new int(5));
    auto p2 = std::move(p); // should be error?
    std::cout << *p2 << std::endl; // 5
    return 0;
}
```

You can try it online [here](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/466a135b195bf48f).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`p` is not `const`.  See [here](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ff3dd74a6e8e1d1a) for it to fail the way you expect.

`auto` deduces like a `template<class T>void foo(T)` does.  `T` is never deduced as `const`, and neither is `auto p=`.

Meanwhile, the `auto p =` line works because you compiled it in [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) mode.  In [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) [it does not compile](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e066e897480a2485).  This is because how prvalues differ in 17; some call the difference guaranteed elision.

If you want an immobile unique ptr:

```
template<class T, class D>
struct immobile_ptr:private std::unique_ptr<T, D>{
  using unique_ptr<T>::operator*;
  using unique_ptr<T>::operator->;
  using unique_ptr<T>::get;
  using unique_ptr<T>::operator bool;
  // etc

  // manually forward some ctors, as using grabs some move ctors in this case
};
template<class T, class...Args>
immobile_ptr<T> make_immobile_ptr(Args&&...args); // todo
```

an alternative might be to take a unique ptr with an immobile destroyer.

```
template<class X>
struct nomove_destroy:std::destroy<T>{
  nomove_destroy(nomove_destroy&&)=delete;
  nomove_destroy()=default;
  nomove_destroy& operator=(nomove_destroy&&)=delete;
};
template<class T>
using nomove_ptr=std::unique_ptr<T,nomove_destroy<T>>;
```

But I am uncertain if that will work.

Comment: If I read [overload #6](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/unique_ptr) correctly, the deleter trick should work. Neat!

Answer (score 3):

Note that `p` is declared as non-reference type, the `const` part of the argument `scoped_ptr<int>(new int(5))` is ignored in type deduction. Then the type deduction result for `p` is `std::unique_ptr<int>`, not `const std::unique_ptr<int>` (i.e. `scoped_ptr<int>` as you expected).

What you want might be

```
auto& p = scoped_ptr<int>(new int(5)); // p is of type const std::unique_ptr<int>& now
```

Comment: `auto&` doesn't make it of non-reference type `const std::unique_ptr<int>`, does it?

Comment: @ShadowRanger You mean `const std::unique_ptr<int>&` ?

Comment: Works  across versions this way https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/aef0f48df5604e38

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to the world of **type deduction** in C++. Try

```
auto & p = scoped_ptr<int>(new int(5));
```

or

```
auto && p = scoped_ptr<int>(new int(5));
```

instead. This lecture may be helpful: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wQxj20X-tIU

Comment: Thanks for the suggested lecture - I think I need to watch this and read the relevant material from Modern Effective C++ again :)